# Adding a Key Listener to a JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a JTextArea called input and I am trying to get the string inputValue loaded into it when I press the up arrow key. so far this code does not seem to work and I am unsure as to why. Please help.

```
    input.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {            
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                input.setText(inputValue);
                System.out.println("up is pressed");
            }       
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener with Swing text components as they can mess up the native functioning of the component. There are much better ways to trap keypresses in these components including use of DocumentListeners, DocumentFilters and Key Bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should override void keypressed instead of keytyped

```
@Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                input.setText(inputValue);
                System.out.println("up is pressed");

        }
```

because it's not a caracter

Answer (score 7):

You should take care when using low level listeners like KeyListeners on Swing text components like JTextAreas, since messing with these can cause the text component to misbehave.

Much better is to use a DocumentListener if you're looking for changes to the document or a DocumentFilter if you want to listen for and block or change text entry *before* it occurs.

If you just want to be notified of keys such as the up arrow, I'd use Key Bindings -- what the JTextArea uses itself to be notified of and react to key presses, and would replace the key binding with the new one. If you do this with care, you can even call the original action tied to the key press in your new Action. For instance:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextAreaTrapUp extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);

    public TextAreaTrapUp() {
        // get JTextArea's InputMap and ActionMap
        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
        InputMap inputMap = textArea.getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = textArea.getActionMap();

        // get the up keystroke
        KeyStroke upKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0);
        String upKey = (String) inputMap.get(upKeyStroke); // get the input map's key for this keystorke
        Action originalUpAction = actionMap.get(upKey); // and get the action map's original action for this key

        Action newUpAction = new NewUpAction(originalUpAction); // create our new up action passing in the old one
        actionMap.put(upKey, newUpAction); // and set this into our ActionMap

        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
    }

    // Action called when up-arrow pressed
    private class NewUpAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Action originalUpAction; // the original action

        public NewUpAction(Action originalUpAction) {
            this.originalUpAction = originalUpAction;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Up Arrow Pressed");

            // if you want to move the caret up, then call the original action
            // as well
            if (originalUpAction != null) {
                originalUpAction.actionPerformed(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TextAreaTrapUp mainPanel = new TextAreaTrapUp();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextAreaTrapUp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into this issue earlier when using an action listener on swing components. I ended up using thread locking to sort out the glitch but I think this might have worked better in the long run. oh well.

Comment: @CNorlander: I'm not sure that I understood your last comment. But a question: why are you trapping the up-arrow press within a JTextArea, as that's somewhat of an unusual requirement? And are you wanting the up-arrow to also function as it should -- to move the caret up? And a small side consideration: consider up-voting all answers that show effort to try to help you.

Comment: The text area is used for input in a text adventure game and is disabled when input from the user is not desired. I don't want the user to be able to use this up arrow command when the field is not enabled. the up arrow key does not need to perform its normal function.