# Output on keyPressed in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener

When I am trying to get text from `JTextArea` and print it, it is printing the string after the next key is pressed I want to print it when I press the key.

The code is given below:

```
textArea_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            x=textArea_1.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(x);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

For example First I pressed 's' key then I pressed 'a' key
The output after pressing 'a' key is s
The output after pressing 's' key is null
But I want s just after i pressed 's' key

Comment: You're probably better off using a DocumentListener as per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754412/522444). Avoid using KeyListeners on Swing text components as they are low-level constructs and your listener could potentially mess with the underlying functionality of the component.

Comment: .... or Key Bindings if you must respond to keys being *typed* into the text component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, you can use a **DocumentListener**, for example:

```
javax.swing.event.DocumentListener myDocumentListener = new javax.swing.event.DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        output(documentEvent);
    }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        output(documentEvent);
    }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        output(documentEvent);
    }
    private void output(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        Document source = documentEvent.getDocument();
        int length = source.getLength();
        try {
            System.out.println(source.getText(0, length));
        }
        catch (javax.swing.text.BadLocationException ex) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Index Supplied!");
        }
    }
};
jTextArea1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(myDocumentListener);
```

Comment: Yep. The main downside to this is that it does not differentiate between data entry by key-strokes vs data entry (or removal) by copy-paste, or by code. 1+